# AngularJS: Second app in template doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I have two identical apps (apart from app/controller name) right after each other. The first one works as expected, the second one is apparently not executed at all.

My code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bew5q0r/)):

```http
<div ng-app="passwdtool" ng-controller="PasswordController">
Password: <input ng-model="pass" required type="text"><br>
<span>{{ hash }}</span><br>
</div>

<div ng-app="passwdtool2" ng-controller="PasswordController2">
Password: <input ng-model="pass" required type="text"><br>
<span>{{ hash }}</span><br>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('passwdtool', [])
.controller('PasswordController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pass = "password";
  $scope.hash = "a hash";
}]);

angular.module('passwdtool2', [])
.controller('PasswordController2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pass = "password";
  $scope.hash = "a hash";
}]);
```

The output:

> Password: [`password`]
>   a hash
>   Password: []
>   {{ hash }}

What is going on?

Comment: Angular only boots the first ng-app. The second one should be booted manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS tries to find the first ng-app and boots it.
If your are defining other ng-app  inside the html, you will have to explicitly boot them.

The function for that is :

```
angular.bootstrap(<elements on which the ng-app will be attached>, <ng-app name>);
```

In your case it should be like:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('app2'); //attach app2 id to the element.
angular.bootstrap(domElement, ["passwdtool2"]);
```

This functions is used in case you want multiple ng-apps on the same page.
See this fiddle, I have modified on yours:
https://jsfiddle.net/7bew5q0r/2/

Plus, you dont even need the second ng-app, since angular is going to ignore it anyway.
So updating that: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7bew5q0r/3/